# CRUD error in view when DB is empty in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel-6

I am trying to make a CRUD page using a single view. When I have data in the DB its displaying my table without any errors. However, if the DB is empty, its displays the error as the following.

> Undefined variable: Product

Please help. What am I doing wrong?

**ProductsController.php**

```php
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::orderBy('name', 'asc')->paginate();

    return view('products')->with('Products', $products);
}

public function create()
{
    return view('products.create');
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('/products', 'ProductsController');
```

**products.blade.php**

```
<table id="example23" class="display nowrap table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
         <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>NO</th>
              <th>SKU</th>
              <th>HSN CODE</th>
              <th>PRODUCT NAME</th>
              <th>QUANTITY</th>
              <th>PRICE</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            @foreach($Products as $Product)
             <tr>
                  <td>{{ $Product->id }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $Product->sku }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $Product->hsn }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $Product->name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $Product->quantity }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $Product->price }}</td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success editbtn">Edit</button></td>
               </tr>
             @endforeach
     </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

**Controller**

```php
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();

    return view('products.index')->with('Products', $products);
}
```

**View**

```php
<table id="example23" class="display nowrap table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>SKU</th>
        <th>HSN CODE</th>
        <th>PRODUCT NAME</th>
        <th>QUANTITY</th>
        <th>PRICE</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @if(!$Products->isEmpty())
        @foreach($Products as $Product)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $Product->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $Product->sku }}</td>
                <td>{{ $Product->hsn }}</td>
                <td>{{ $Product->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $Product->quantity }}</td>
                <td>{{ $Product->price }}</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success editbtn">Edit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <tr>
            <td>You do not have any products to display.</td>
        </tr>
    @endif
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In the Controller index() try... return view('products.index')->with('Products', $products);

Comment: Also on the command line try: php artisan route:list. And post the result.

Comment: Sorry !! error was appearing because of bootstrap model code below that table at view page for editing the data, as its trying to fetch from db without checking. Could you please help me out with updating the data with bootstrap modal i tried with version below 6, none of them were submitting.

Comment: try to assign a value in like this `paginate(5)`